# How to compare the strings in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have a problem in writing mySql query.

Example:

I have two input fields.

1. Title = "Live to Tell";
2. Composer = "Madonna/Michel Jackson";

In my database table contains the below records

Table name: SONGS   with columns Title and Composer

1. Title = "Live to Tell";
2. Composer = "Michel Jackson/Madonna";

My Query:

```
select * from SONGS 
where title ='Live to Tell' and 
composer ='Madonna/Michel Jackson'
```

Does not return results. I interchanged the word in the composer filed.

My requirement is to make it work even we interchange the words.

Composer content is separated by '/'

Comment: Read your query out loud.  How can a title be both 'Live To Tell' and 'Madonna/Michel Jackson'?

Comment: This looks like a job for data normalization (among other things).  Storing multiple values in a single field makes them *a single value*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look fulltext search functionalities on MySql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

But may be this is not enough for your condition, you will need external search engines like elastic search.

Answer (score 1):

Try exploding the string `Madonna/Michel Jackson` with php function [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Before using it in your query.

```
$composer = explode('/', 'Madonna/Michel Jackson');
```

This returns an array into `$composer` looking like this:

```
array(
   [0] => 'Madonna',
   [1] => 'Michel Jackson'
)
```

To select one of the names you can use, `$composer[0] or $composer[1]`

```
SELECT * FROM songs WHERE title ='Live to Tell' AND composer LIKE "%$composer[1]%";
```